# How to prevent the mirror imaging issue on Xamarin UWP

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uwp, camera

Hi I have a Xamarin application, I need to scan some items(Debit card, Id card) through camera and upload the same to server. Implemented the camera functionality through Xamarin.Essential.Media and it's working on iOS back camera. But in UWP am facing the camera mirroring issue, is there any solution for this. And also how to prevent the iOS front camera. Here is my code.

```
 var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
 if (photo == null)
 { return;}

 byte[] imgByte;
 using (var bytestream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
  {
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 bytestream.CopyTo(ms);    

 imgByte = ms.ToArray()
   }
```

[image: While capturing]
While Capturing

[image]

After Taking, how to avoid the mirroring while capturing the image

Comment: my printer app gives me a preview with the option to mirror my image before i save it , might work for you as well

Comment: In preview it coming correctly, but I need the same in while taking also

Comment: Do you mean it seems correct in the Camera preview but when you save it into the photo, the image will get mirrored? Also, you are testing using a laptop and using its front camera?

Comment: If you just need to display the image in correct direction, you just need set the `RotationY` property of the image control.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT updated with screenshot

Comment: For UWP, you might need to take a look at this [Handle device orientation with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/handle-device-orientation-with-mediacapture#add-orientation-data-to-the-camera-preview-stream). You might need to create a custom preview.  But based on the image you posted, it seems the captured photo is in right direction, and you don't need to modify it.